# How to get Python Class to Return Some Data and not its Object Address

Tags: python, oop, methods, pandas, representation

### Context:

Using the following:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 2

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._x)

    def __call__(self):
        return self._x
```

Then creating an instance with `t = test()`

I see how to use `__str__` for print:

```
>>> print t
2
```

I can see how to make the object callable using `__call__`

```
>>> t()
2
```

### Question

But how do you get the object to return an internal attribute such that when you enter:

```
>>> t
2
```

instead of:

```
<__main__.test instance at 0x000000000ABC6108>
```

in a similar way that `Pandas` prints out `DataFrame` objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Define `__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/190597).

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self._x)
```

The Python interpreter prints the `repr` of the object by default.

Comment: Next time I see you coming, I'll wait ;)

Answer (score 8):

`__repr__` is intended to be the literal **representation** of the object.

Note that if you define `__repr__`, you don't have to define `__str__`, if you want them both to return the same thing. `__repr__` is `__str__`'s fallback.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 2
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._x)
    def __call__(self):
        return self._x

t = test()

>>> print t
2

>>> t
2
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the additional info

Answer (score 0):

Use dir.  Especially from the cli, dir(t) would reveal as much as you need to know about your object t.